# How to speed up the computation of a custom distance matrix over rows of a dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, performance, vectorization

I want to fill in a matrix `M` with values such that `M[i][j] = custom_distance(df.iloc[i], df.iloc[j], *args)` where the custom distance is some non-standard (symmetric) function, and `df` is a dataframe.
What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Currently I'm using a double loop like so:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(i, len(df)):
        M[i][j] = M[j][i] = custom_distance(df.iloc[i], df.iloc[j], arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

EDIT: More info

The function custom_distance is a mix of euclidean distance on the numerical part and matching distance on the categorical part.

```
def matching(a, b):
    return np.sum(a!=b)


def custom_distance(a, b, categorical_indices, numerical_indices):
    numerical_a = a[numerical_indices]
    numerical_b = b[numerical_indices]
    categorical_a = a[categorical_indices]
    categorical_b = b[categorical_indices]

    return euclidean(numerical_a, numerical_b) + matching(categorical_a, categorical_b)
```

Comment: If what you are trying to do is compute the distance matrix between m points in an N-dimensional space using a custom distance metric, look at scipy's `pdist` and `squareform` functions, so something like `distance_matrix = squareform(pdist(X = your_N_dimensional_points, metric = custom_metric`. Regarding speed, you probably will want to optimize your custom metric implementation with `numba` as, from my experience, this is typically where a lot of the time is wasted (scipy's builtin metrics are already optimized so they are very fast, but for custom ones you really need to be careful).

Comment: There is no way to *efficiently* automatically vectorize a black-box function `custom_distance` in Numpy, nor any CPython module as long as `custom_distance` cannot be modified/inspected AFAIK (eg. manually modified or compiled by JITs). Thus, it is not possible to provide an helpful answer to this question without more informations on `custom_distance`. What makes this function slow is calls to `custom_distance`, direct indexing in CPython and possibly the content of `custom_distance`. Please add more information.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I edited the question with more information on the functions. But initially I thought the matrix computation could be made more efficient.

Comment: @Pandora It is better and useful. There are still some unknown though like the type of the values. Besides note that the number of parameters in the call to `custom_distance` does not match with its definition. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that tools like Numba or cython are likely to be the best ones in this case. The Numpy vectorization is fine if your dataframe is not too big.